# run-time error '2465' - can't find field MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a field on a report that is populated by a combo box on a seperate form. I am receiving an error when executing my code stating "can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression - I have the exact same code in a different module in my database and it works without errors so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
Private Sub Reportfilter_bt_Click()

    If IsNull(User_cb.Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please select a user from the dropdown menu", vbCritical, "Database Error"
    Else

        DoCmd.OpenReport "RWA Allocation by User", acViewReport

        [Report_RWA Allocation by User].Filterby_txt.Value = User_cb.Column(1)

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "RWA Task Report"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When you debug, what line does the error point to?

Comment: [Report_RWA Allocation by User].Filterby_txt.Value = User_cb.Column(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that access could not find my report even though the name was correct. I had to add it as a Microsoft Access Class Object before the code would run without any errors.